# Using bc in bash for loop array doesn't calculate first input?

Tags: bash, for-loop, syntax-error

I'm struggling to pass a multi-row array of floating-point numbers through a for loop, have it run a calculation, then define a new variable from the outputs.

Here's a simplified version of my Bash:

```
inputs=$(echo "12.12
34.34")

New_array=$( for var in "${inputs[@]}"; do
                 echo "${var}*2"| bc -l;
             done )
```

I would expect the result from `echo "$New_array"` to be this:

```
$ echo "$New_array"
24.24
68.68
```

But I get this?

```
$ echo "$New_array"
12.12
68.68
```

Or whilst I've been troubleshooting (e.g. removing the `$New_array` variable):

```
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
```

I *believe* the problem has something to do with line return being read as an input for the first loop? But the solutions I've tried haven't worked so far.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You have no arrays in that code...

Comment: Can you add the command you use to run the script?

Comment: @kpie, just `bash scriptname.sh`? I've only been debugging this in the terminal if that helps?

Comment: Neither of your variables is actually an array, they're both just strings with a newline in the middle (making them two lines of text), but the way you're looping over `inputs` requires it to be an actual array. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70335266), and [this one on the Unix&Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/672182). Do you actually want to use arrays (generally cleaner), or multiline strings? BTW, `$(echo something)` is almost always a mistake -- the `$( )` and `echo` basically cancel each other out.

Comment: @GordonDavisson I suspect `echo` is a simplification for example purposes, and the real code will be `inputs=$(some actual command)`

Comment: To make an array from command output, use `inputs=($(some command))`. One set of parentheses for the array, the other for `$(command)`

Comment: Ah-ha! Thanks for that, @GordonDavisson!

I understand what you mean. What I was calling an 'array' was instead being interpreted as a series of strings. As a result they lacked any index, meaning it couldn't be read by the `for loop` in an iterative fashion.

I redefined test as unquoted values within `$( )` and it worked!

Seems defining things as arrays is the way to go, so I'll rework my input.

If you care a touch of extra rep', feel free answer.

Comment: @KyranMcDonnell Some other notes: if you aren't using an actual array, you should remove the `[@]` (i.e. use `$inputs` or `${inputs}` instead of `${inputs[@]}`). Also, beware that using unquoted variables will cause anything that looks like a filename wildcard to expand into a list of matching filenames, e.g. in `2 * 3`, the `*` will be replaced by a list of filenames in the current directory. This is one of the reasons that actual arrays are preferred.

Comment: An array is mandatory? I think your problem is the x2

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you are trying to do:

```
#!/bin/bash

inputs=(12.12 34.34)

for var in "${inputs[@]}"; do
    New_array+=("$(bc -l <<< "$var * 2")")
done
printf '%s\n' "${New_array[@]}"
```

Note that `inputs=(12.12 34.34)` creates an array named `inputs` having elements `12.12` and `34.34`. `New_array+=(...)` appends an element (here, the output of the command `bc -l <<< "$var * 2"`) to the array `New_array`. Alternatively, this could be done at once using `printf`'s implicit loop and `mapfile` builtin of `bash`:

```
mapfile -t New_array < <(printf '%s * 2\n' "${inputs[@]}" | bc -l)
```

If it is guaranteed that the elements of the array don't contain whitespace and glob characters (this is probably the case here), then this could be an alternative way:

```
New_array=($(printf '%s * 2\n' "${inputs[@]}" | bc -l))
```